# Submit Event Not Firing on Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a webpage with a control to handle all the comments so I don't have to copy the code from one page to another.  When I click the button, the code to handle the submit is not happening.  I want the page to have no .axd references.

This is my form statement on the .aspx page

```
<form id="formAlpha" method="post" runat="server" action="">
    <Comm:Comm ID="comments" runat="server" />
</form>
```

The processing for saving the comments is in the control.aspx

In the code of the webpage, I set the action to be

```
    formAlpha.Action = Request.RawUrl;
```

This is my submit button in the control.

```
<asp:button ID="cmdSubmit" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="true" text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="cmdSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateSubmission();" />
```

The JS code executes correctly, it displays an alert box and then returns true.  THe page reloads but the click event doesn't work.  The load event fires up again and the IsPostBack is false.  Its not submitting but reloading.

I'm using WebForms C#, not MVC

Comment: Is your button in the form?

Comment: Submit button is on control as opposed to the aspx along with the handled code.

Comment: Ok, your HTML result seems correct?

Comment: The ValidateSubmission javascript works but the details don't go back to the C#, is always IsPostBack = false.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is possible that your form is inside another form? Have you try to move button from control directly into the form?

Comment: No form inside another form.  Have move everything to the form out of the control and still nothing :( Javascript fires but the c# event doesn't fire.

Comment: Make sure there is no `Response.Redirect` in your code-behind or in the server control that you are using. If this  redirect is executed before the click handler is reached in code-behind, then you could see that page always reloads and the click handler of button never gets  executed.

Comment: Also, make sure that all script tags in your page are properly closed.

Comment: Also, are you setting action for form in Page_Load or some other page event?

Comment: Action is set in Page_Load, I'm setting Action to Request.RawURL.  I'm using IIS Rewrites as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea taken from the [official MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx), remove the "return" (and maybe the semicolon too) keyword from the onClientClick declaration:

OnClientClick="ValidateSubmission()"